# Double delayed expansion in batch?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to double my delayed expansion if that makes any sense. Here is what I want.

```
set var1=hello
set var2=var1
set var3=var2
echo %!%var3%!%
```

and then have `hello` be displayed. This is not my actual code but an example of how I need it to work.

Answer (score 6):

You could add a `call` and surround your first delayed expansion with double percents like this.

```js
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "var1=hello"
set "var2=var1"
set "var3=var2"

call echo %%!%var3%!%%
```

Seems horribly convoluted to me, though.  I'd probably rewrite the script to make such trickery not needed if I were me.

---

**Edit:** Since there are so many solutions being added here, I'll propose another one.  Here's a subroutine that will follow the line of variables from beginning to end, even if it's 1000 levels deep.  Just as an academic exercise.

```js
@echo off
setlocal

set "var1=hello"
for /L %%I in (2,1,1000) do (
    set /a X = %%I - 1
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    for %%x in (!X!) do endlocal & set "var%%I=var%%x"
)

call :follow var1000
goto :EOF

:follow <varname>
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "var=!%~1!"
:follow_loop
if defined !%var%! (
    set "var=!%var%!" & goto follow_loop
) else (
    echo !%var%!
)
```

And here's another using a batch + JScript hybrid (because the JScript `while` loop is faster than a batch `goto` loop).

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
setlocal

set "var1=hello"
for /L %%I in (2,1,1000) do (
    set /a X = %%I - 1
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    for %%x in (!X!) do endlocal & set "var%%I=var%%x"
)

cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" "var1000"
goto :EOF

@end // end batch / begin JScript hybrid chimera
var env = WSH.CreateObject('Wscript.Shell').Environment('Process'),
    itm = WSH.Arguments(0);

while (env(itm)) itm = env(itm);

WSH.Echo(itm);
```

Your move, Aacini.

Comment: Your code have an error in the creation of the variables. See my edit.

Comment: @Aacini fixed, I think.

Answer (score 6):

even possible without delayed expansion (although even uglier than rojo's answer) Just a matter of the number of "layers" of parsing and correct escaping the `%`:

```
@echo off
set var1=hello
set var2=var1
set var3=var2
call call echo %%%%%%%var3%%%%%%%
```

Comment: I was just editing my answer to include this.  Great minds think alike!

Answer (score 6):

Another one without `call` (faster):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "var1=hello"
set "var2=var1"
set "var3=var2"

for %%v in (!%var3%!) do echo !%%v!
```

---

**EDIT**: *Reply to rojo's challenge*

Your code have an error in the creation of the variables; all variables contain the string: "var!X!" and the final result is "var!X!X". Below is your code with the variables creation part fixed:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "var1=hello"
for /L %%I in (2,1,1000) do (
    set /a X = %%I - 1
    set "var%%I=var!x!"
)

call :follow var1000
goto :EOF

:follow <varname>
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "var=!%~1!"
:follow_loop
if defined !%var%! (
    set "var=!%var%!" & goto follow_loop
) else (
    echo !%var%!
)
```

This program correctly show "hello" at end; it takes about 2.51 seconds when run in my computer.

The method is pretty short, so there is not too much chance to improve it; the obvious modification is to change the `goto` loop by a `for` (while) one. Here it is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "var1=hello"
for /L %%I in (2,1,1000) do (
    set /a X = %%I - 1
    set "var%%I=var!x!"
)

call :follow var1000
goto :EOF


:follow <varname>
set "var=%~1"
cmd /V:ON /C for /L %%? in () do @for %%v in (^^!var^^!) do @if defined %%v (set "var=^!%%v^!") else echo %%v ^& exit
```

This code takes about 1.22 seconds to run, that is, just the 48.6% of your method (2 times faster) **`;)`**

Comment: Master.  I regret that I have but one +1 to give.  But I think you're mistaken about there being an error in my code.  When I run mine the output is `help`.

Comment: @rojo: Your first code show this result here: `var!X!X`. I inserted a `SET VAR` command before the `call` and got this: `var1=hello` `var10=var!X!` `var100=var!X!` `var1000=var!X!` `var101=var!X!` ... The hybrid code show: `var!X!`  Windows 8.1 here...

Comment: That's so weird.  My WIn10 home theater PC ran my script as expected, but my Win10 laptop gave the same results as you got.  I moved the `endlocal` in my script and it's working now on the laptop.  I just tested my JScript hybrid vs. your pure batch solution.  Mine averaged 2.6 seconds.  Yours, 2.55 seconds.  I use PowerShell's `Measure-Command` cmdlet to time the execution.

Comment: @rojo: Do you mean that my pure Batch code run _faster_ than your JScript hybrid one? **`^_^`** This is very interesting!