# Batch : Dynamic variable name (eval equivalent)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a variable containing the name of an environnent variable. I would like to eval this value. For example:

```
:: TOTO_1_2 defined outside of batch file
set varName="TOTO_1_2"
echo %TOTO_1_2% :: Display env var
echo %%varName%% :: Broken
```

The idea is to pass the value of the env var pointed by varName to a command then.

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33899436/double-delayed-expansion-in-batch

Answer (score 13, accepted):

if you want to evaluate a evaluated variable, you have to parse it twice:

There are different possibilities to do that. Here are three of them:

```
@echo off
SET TOTO_1_2=hello
set "varName=TOTO_1_2"
echo 0: %TOTO_1_2% 
call echo 1: %%%varName%%%

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%i in (%varname%) do echo 2: !%%i!
echo 3: !%varName%!
```

Comment: Thanks, very userful. Incredible how the most basic of things, such as dereferencing twice, can be so non-trivial in a batch file.

Comment: Awesome! To be honest, I was a bit confused by the "1:", "2:", "3:" until I saw that it is just the enumeration. For me, version 3 was the most useful.