# Batch: Dynamic variable name but with a function parameter

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a variable containing the name of a parameter on a function. I would like to evaluate this value inside the function. For example:

```
SET "functionVariable=%%~%1"
CALL :defineChapters 15
:defineChapters
CALL ECHO %%%functionVariable%%%
```

In this example I want to have

```
15
```

on the output instead of

```
%~1
```

My case is pretty similar to this one [Batch : Dynamic variable name (eval equivalent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34103871/batch-dynamic-variable-name-eval-equivalent/34104130) but instead of having a variable containing another variable's name, it contains a function's parameter name

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you try to do, but this code show the result you want (a `15`):

```
@echo off
setlocal

SET "functionVariable=%%~1"
CALL :defineChapters 15
goto :EOF


:defineChapters
CALL ECHO %functionVariable%
exit /B
```

Comment: Worked, thanks
Sorry for the unclear context, I tried to simplify to let only what I couldn't do